# Java need help about constructors

Tags: java, constructor

My assignment (edit full asssignment now)

- Make a class Punt with the properties defined above ( a coordinate needs a to be defined with a x and  y value. Choose the right data types.
- Make 2 constructors for the class Punt
- One constructor that accepts no arguments and initialize it to (0,0)
- One constructor that accept two arguments the x and y coordinates this one has to be initialized to the x and y value and has their respective values as arguments

  Make a print() method in the class Punt  that prints the coordinates.
  •     Test the Punt class by doing the following in the main() class called Main.
  o       Make one object from Punt by using the constructor without arguments.
  o       Make another object in Punt using the other constructor ( the one with 2 argumentS).
  o       Call from both objects the print method and check if the output is correct

My question is what Datatypes should i use? An int for x and an int for y or should I use a double? Also for the constructor that accepts no arguments how should i write this?

this class will

Comment: You can better go with double..

Comment: Don't use floating-point coordinates for points...

Comment: so use doubles for coordinates?

Comment: Seeing as we have no idea how you want to use this class, how would we know?

Comment: @RohitJain Could you explain (to me) my would **you** choose double for coordinates. My usual approach is that any finite value should be represented with finite data type, and I don't see any need for infinite precision (or in fact **imprecision**) here.

Comment: @GermannArlington thank you... this is really about Points and not about floating-point inaccuracy. But both are strong arguments.

Comment: @GermannArlington.. That completely depends upon how much precision OP needs in this case.. If of course he wants to mark a point (1.5, 2.5), how you are gonna do it with an int?? On the other hand, you can of course mark (1, 2) with a double..

Comment: Java has both double and int-based point datatypes built right into the standard library.  They're both useful at different times, depending on when you're modelling a discrete coordinate system (e.g. a chess board) or a continuous one (e.g. the real world).  There's no point advocating for one or the other with zero context.  Everybody's right.

Comment: I think the required precision is mentioned in the specification... It would've said 0.0, 0.0 if the teacher wanted continuity or he would have hinted it somehow. In any case, that's completely besides the issue here :D this is standard homework.

Comment: @RohitJain Re: precision and presentation => 1.3 = 13 (10ths), 1.3715 = 13715 (10,000ths) in int/long representation. This was the way of representing any finite precision numbers (currency/weight/distance...) for years and it is considerably more precise than float/double representation of the same.

Answer (score 2):

The data types you use depend on your design decisions.  How much specificity do you want your grid to have?  Do you want all `Punt`s to fall exactly on a grid line, or do you want there to be degrees in between on your plane?  If the former, use an `int`; if the latter, use a `double`.  This decision doesn't require any real programming knowledge, just some critical thinking.

A no-argument constructor is written the same way you would write a no-argument method.

```
public Punt() {

    //Do stuff

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Punt
{
    private int x, y;

    public Punt()
    {
       this(0,0);
    }

    public Punt(int x, int y)
    {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
    }

    public void print()
    {
         System.out.println("(X, Y) = ("+x+", "+y+")");
    }
}
```

JB Nizet did make a valid point.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Punt p1 = new Punt();
        Punt p2 = new Punt(-2, -1);

        p1.print();
        p2.print();
    }
}
```

might as well finish it now...

Comment: OP isn't asking to give him the Code.. And even if he asks, you should not..

Comment: You didn't answer the OP's questions, you simply completed his assignment.  Furthermore, you completed it in one of the least proper ways possible.  (The call to `this()` is unnecessary, the formatting is awkward, encapsulation is disregarded, the default constructor is private without reason).

Comment: And why you chose the two-arg constructor to call the no-arg one, instead of doing the much more logical reverse thing.

Comment: a picture is worth a thousand words. so is working code. The only reason I used ints is because there were no specifications regarding precision and I just presume he has no good argument for having floating-point coordinates for points. In other words, my points are discreete.

Comment: @Vulcan: when i was in school and I didn't understand something, there was no itnernet i could ask people. instead, i had to look at the answer and figure out why that answer is the answer. "to talk with the solution" is the idea here. Feel free to provide a better one - but instead of me justifying why i did this and that, the student should be asking those questions to HIMSELF and trying to come up with the answer HIMSELF. We can go on and on about the perfect way to do this homework but it's not about me, or you, or his homework. It's about him learning how to do it by example.

Comment: thanks i had the second constructor already myself, only didnt know how to make the first one

Comment: Well Tim, there you go. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: @Shark I understand that, but now that the internet exists, there's no harm in providing an explanation along with an answer, especially when the explanation is what the questioner desires.  Your answer is now acceptable seeing that it follows proper standards, and I've upvoted it, because explanations have been posted via comments.

Comment: Thank you very much good sir. *smirks* I don't really wanna go on about teaching college kids or how they only want answers or how they can't even explain what they want... Whats done is done, my VMs are down, my computer is working stable again so I can shut it down, go home and call it a day. But thinking for oneself is the biggest reward you can get out of this, and I would've very much more prefferred if he asked me "why is this ctor calling the other one" instead of you guys bandwagoning me that it should be done the other way around. So i decided you might as well fill in the details...

Answer (score 1):

How much precision do you need? Are your coordinates going to be only part of the integers or the reals? That should answer your question about what data type. Oracles JavaDocs have a few pages on [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Comment: its going to be something like (0,0) and (-2,1) etc.

Comment: In that case integers would be fine. If you wanted to have (1.5, 2.3) you would need floats or doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Datatype you should use is dependent on what this class will be used for. If you need only integrals - use int, if you need more precision use non-integrals (double takes more space in memory and since you don't have any specific requirements concerning precision float seems to be the most reasonable choice).